# Directory contents in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filepath

Is there a way of returning a list of files in a directory with their absolute paths.

When I do

```
getDirectoryContents dir
```

it gives me a list of filenames in the directory. If I am using these filenames at another place, I need to know their absolute paths or the paths relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
getAbsDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsDirectoryContents dir =
  getDirectoryContents dir >>= mapM (canonicalizePath . (dir </>))
```

This uses [System.Directory.canonicalizePath](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v:canonicalizePath), and works even if `dir` is not an absolute path (e.g. if you call `getAbsDirectoryContents "foo"` and then move elsewhere in the filesystem).

If you know that `dir` is an absolute path, you can instead use:

```
getAbsDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsDirectoryContents dir = map (dir </>) <$> getDirectoryContents dir
```

which uses [System.FilePath.(</>)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:-60--47--62-), and might be a bit faster.

Comment: Might be worth noting that for this solution to work, you need to import System.FilePath (</>) and Data.Functor (<$>)

Answer (score 3):

```
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)
import System.FilePath ((</>))

getAbsoluteDirContents :: String -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsoluteDirContents dir = do
  contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
  return $ map (dir </>) contents
```